# Is this the correct way to implement a retry loop (until successful)?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run a retry loop for a command that should repeat itself until successfully ran. On a single run, suppose the command I'm running produces the following output text to the console/Terminal.

```
TextLine1

TextLine2
100.00%|TextLine3
```

In a separate experimental script, I set outputText string variable to the command output, which prints `100.00%`, as expected

```
outputText="TextLine1

TextLine2
100.00%|TextLine3"

echo $outputText | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7
```

Somehow, I'm not able to put it into another variable. I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
out2=$($outputText | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7)
echo $out2
```

In the Terminal, I get `Logging: command not found`, and it prints out a blank line at the step `echo $out2`. Either way, so I put the entire command into the variable. In the end it looks like this.

```
cmd=$(fullCommand | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7)
```

I let it execute and complete and there are two things. First is that it doesn't store the expected output to the `cmd` variable. Because in the next line, I ran `echo $cmd`, but in the actual run, it prints a blank. The full code block looks like this.

```
cmd=$(fullCommand | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7)
while [ $cmd != "100.00%" ]; do
    cmd=$(fullCommand | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7)
done
```

In the while loop part of the console, it says `./script.sh: line 24: [: !=: unary operator expected`, which I think is because nothing got stored in the variable in the previous line. Thus, the while loop would fail to execute. Is there any way to store the "filtered" `100.00%` into the variable `cmd` then compare it to `100.00%` in the while loop header?

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions: `[ "$cmd" != "100.00%" ]` Paste your script into https://shellcheck.net and fix they mentioned thing.

Comment: `out2=$(echo $outputText | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7)` -- you need to write `$outputText` on `stdout` using `echo` or `printf` (or using bash, feed it to `awk` using a *herestring*) E.g. `awk '{print $8}' <<< $outputText`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thanks! So if I `stdout` to a variable, I can monitor the progress, then the filtered content should be stored into a variable via `<<<`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That doesn't seem to work. I did `fullCommand <<< $cmd`, then `echo $cmd`. The command runs fine, but looks like the multi-line output never got stored into the `$cmd` variable. This explains why running `echo $cmd` afterwards returns a blank. Any other way to do this?

Comment: If you don't have bash, `echo "some stuff"` outputs `some stuff` on `stdout` and when you pipe that to another process using `|`, that `stdout` is used as `stdin` for the process piped to. Bash make it even easier, it adds a *herestring*. So instead of having to pipe the variable contents, you can simply read the variable contest on `stdin` with `<<< $thevar`.

Comment: Using *herestring* it would be `out2=$(awk '{print $8}' <<< $outputText | cut -c1-7)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hmm... still doesn't work. So the command takes around 15 minutes to fully execute, and produces three lines of output. As a quick test, I put all three lines of output (as a string) into a variable `$testing`. I'm able to do `echo $testing` and it outputs everything just fine. But if I want to transfer that to another variable using the `<<<` operator, it doesn't work. In the quick test, I did `echo $testing <<< $test2`. Then I tried to do `echo $test2`, which outputs nothing. If running the actual command, it will produce that output, which needs to be stored via `<<<`

Comment: `cmd=$(fullCommand | awk '{print $8}' | cut -c1-7)` is correct *Unless* `fullCommand` does not write to `stdout`. The `while [ $cmd != "100.00%" ]; do` looks like an endless loop unless what is output by `fullCommand` changes magically between immediately before the loop and then within the loop.